# Undefined offset in custom codeigniter library, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined

I'll have a view php errors in my code, that causes two errors with both $time and $date array. Php says Message: Undefined offset: 1 and 2 for both $time and $date.

So the keys after i've done explode(), are undefined? How and why is this exactly? And how do i solve this issue? The array display results from the database which i can see when using print_r.

```
 Array ( [0] => 05 [1] => 51 [2] => 00 ) 
 Array ( [0] => 1984 [1] => 06 [2] => 23 )
```

I tried quite couple things, none seem to work. I don't remember i had this issue ever before... I'll almost start thinking that maybe the problem could have something to do with Codeigniter?

```css
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Sweph {
 
 public $julian_ut = null; 
 
 public $config = array();
 
 public $chart_id='';
 
 public $user_id='';
 
 public $chart_name='';
 
 public $chart_time='';
 
 public $chart_date='';
 
 public $chart_search='';
 
 public $chart_timezone='';
 
 public $chart_houses='';
 
 public $chart_longitude='';
 
 public $chart_latitude='';
 
 public $time = array();
 
 public $date = array();
 
 /***
  * Initialize chart details
  **/
 public function __construct($config=array()) {

  // Get instance 
  $this->CI =& get_instance();  
  
  // Initializes and Loads Ephemeris files from Directory
  swe_set_ephe_path(FCPATH.'ephemeris');
 
  // Creates objects from config array
  foreach ($config as $property => $value)
                {
                     $this->$property = $value;
                } 
  
  // Create time and date array
  $time = explode(":", $this->chart_time);
  $date = explode("-", $this->chart_date);
  
  // Calculates Julian day 
  $this->julian_ut = swe_julday(intval($date[0]), $date[1], $date[2], ($time[0] + $time[1] / 60 + $time[2] / 3600) , SE_GREG_CAL); 
  
        }

 /***
  * Return time/day in julian day number
  **/ 
 public function get_julian_ut() {
  return $this->julian_ut;
 }

}
```

** Errors **

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: libraries/Sweph.php

Line Number: 61

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 2

Filename: libraries/Sweph.php

Line Number: 61

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: libraries/Sweph.php

Line Number: 61

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 2

Filename: libraries/Sweph.php

Line Number: 61

**Update:** Forgot to mention array has results from database and added errors.

Comment: Which file it cause error at view or inside controller.write the full error message.

Comment: Updated the question, its custom library for codeigniter.

Comment: It should not produce the error if your both array has value.Hard to produce the scenario.Try to `echo $time[2];die();` after explode. is there producing error again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check its `var_dump()` and then use the **indexes** it accordingly.

```
$time = explode(":", $this->chart_time);
var_dump($time);

$date = explode("-", $this->chart_date);
var_dump($date);
```

But this is **not the right way** to get date, month or time out of date and time.

**Recommended:**

```
<?php
$date = '2015-01-22';
$time = '18:16:12';

$dt = new DateTime($date);
$tm = new DateTime($time);

$day = $dt->format('d');
$month = $dt->format('m');
$year = $dt->format('Y');

$hour = $tm->format('H');
$min = $tm->format('i');
$sec = $tm->format('s');
```

**Demo:**
http://3v4l.org/VDB7l

**Documentation:**
http://docs.php.net/class.datetime

Comment: It return the results: Array ( [0] => 05 [1] => 51 [2] => 00 ); So they array is not empty...

Comment: Can you try the other way I've added?

Comment: The data in the array comes from the database, something i forgot to mention.

Comment: I have tested your scenario. http://3v4l.org/V0fXu. Check if it the same at your end. Try `echo` at every moment to know what values you are getting.

Comment: Results in: Hour=05 Min=51 Sec=00 Year=1984 Mon=06 Day=23 Exactly as it should result in.

Comment: Try removing this. I guess this is overwriting the array with blank. `public $time = array();
 
 public $date = array();`

Comment: Thanx man, used your recommendations instead of the explode, and the errors are gone. Still makes me wonder, why the keys of the explode are undefined...

Answer (score 1):

```
 $time = explode(":", $this->chart_time);
 //it seems $time does not have value for 1,2 index 
 //$time[1] $time[2] does not exists
```

Thats why you got that warning.
same for

```
 $date = explode("-", $this->chart_date);
```

Make sure $time has minimum 3 size.It will produce same warning if the size is less than 3.

Comment: Both array produce results: Array1 ( [0] => 05 [1] => 51 [2] => 00 ) Array2 ( [0] => 1984 [1] => 06 [2] => 23 )

Comment: Question is answered by parag tyagi, but still i`m wondering why something was wrong with explode function. Because the keys had value's...